# How do you make a button in kivy receive a touch without the one below it receiving the touch

Tags: python, events, kivy, touch

I will try and make my question clear.

I have two buttons, the first one is on top of the second one.

When I press the first one, it receives the touch but the second one also receives the touch because the touch occurs within its boundary box.

What do i do in the on_touch_down or on_touch_up function to make the second button below the

first one not to receive the touch or to do nothing with the touch.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you just set the `disabled` property of the second `Button` to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

> What do i do in the on_touch_down or on_touch_up function to make the second button below the
>
> first one not to receive the touch or to do nothing with the touch.

Return True to indicate that you have consumed the touch and it shouldn't keep being passed on.

This should be the default behaviour for buttons, it sounds like you may have broken it by overriding `on_touch_down` without correctly passing out the return value.

Comment: Thanks bro, i've been modifying kivy to make it work the way i want it to and to make my application look good.